# HTTP requests and JSON parsing in Python

Tags: python, json

I want to dynamically query Google Maps through the Google Directions API. As an example, this request calculates the route from Chicago, IL to Los Angeles, CA via two waypoints in Joplin, MO and Oklahoma City, OK:

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=Chicago,IL&destination=Los+Angeles,CA&waypoints=Joplin,MO|Oklahoma+City,OK&sensor=false

It returns a result [in the JSON format](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/intro?csw=1#Waypoints).

How can I do this in Python? I want to send such a request, receive the result and parse it.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20199126/reading-json-from-a-file, for the case where the JSON data is already in a file, or where you already have code that accesses the API using the standard library `urllib` or successors. (Note that the response object in the latter case is a file-like object.)

Comment: [Another great answer can be found here in a different post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28069789/5675325).

Comment: How is this a duplicate of a question asked after this one? Also, how is this a duplicate of a question that asks someting totally different?

Answer (score 503, accepted):

I recommend using the awesome [requests](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/) library:

```
import requests

url = 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json'

params = dict(
    origin='Chicago,IL',
    destination='Los+Angeles,CA',
    waypoints='Joplin,MO|Oklahoma+City,OK',
    sensor='false'
)

resp = requests.get(url=url, params=params)
data = resp.json() # Check the JSON Response Content documentation below
```

JSON Response Content: https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/quickstart/#json-response-content

Comment: For me, I needed to do `json=params` instead of `params=params` or I get a 500 error.

Answer (score 171):

The [`requests`](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) Python module takes care of both retrieving JSON data and decoding it, due to its builtin JSON decoder. Here is an example taken from [the module's documentation](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/quickstart/#json-response-content):

```
>>> import requests
>>> r = requests.get('https://github.com/timeline.json')
>>> r.json()
[{u'repository': {u'open_issues': 0, u'url': 'https://github.com/...
```

So there is no use of having to use some separate module for decoding JSON.

Comment: If you need to be compatible with requests 0.x (Debian wheezy), you should use `json.load()` or `json.loads()` instead, as in 0.x, `json` is a property rather than a function.

Comment: @nyuszika If you are using debian, if somehow possible, use pip to get newer python libraries. You don't want to code with old python libraries, unless there is an important reason to use what debian has in the apt repositories.

Comment: @SHernandez That's a valid point, but some packages might depend on the `python-requests` (or `python3-requests`) package, so you will need to install somewhere else than `/usr/local` to avoid breaking those packages. On the other hand, when portability/compatibility is trivial, in my opinion it's worth it.

Comment: Thats true. I try to use a virtual environments for all user space projects and inside those use a local pip

Comment: How to extract only a particular name-value pair from the json response 'r' ?

Comment: In `r.json()` (from my answer) you have the actual response, JSON-decoded. You can access it like a normal `list`/`dict`; `print r.json()` to see how it looks like. Or refer to the API docs of the service you've made the request for.

Comment: @NikhilGeorge It doesn't appear that .json is chainable.  The only way I have been able to extract a particular key-value pair is to assign the results to an intermediate variable.  `r = requests.get('https://github.com/timeline.json') myJson = r.json() print (myJson['url'])`

Comment: this method needs much more memory

Answer (score 50):

[`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/index.html) has built-in `.json()` method

```
import requests
requests.get(url).json()
```

Answer (score 32):

```
import urllib
import json

url = 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=Chicago,IL&destination=Los+Angeles,CA&waypoints=Joplin,MO|Oklahoma+City,OK&sensor=false'
result = json.load(urllib.urlopen(url))
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, however the following is to be noted :

The urllib.urlopen() function has been removed in Python 3.0 in favor of urllib2.urlopen().

Comment: Arun, yes but it's no longer named urllib2

Comment: It's `urllib.request` in Python 3.

Comment: It does not work. json.loads gives 'TypeError: the JSON object must be str, not 'HTTPResponse'' and json.load gives 'TypeError: the JSON object must be str, not 'bytes''

Comment: wrong again @nyuszika7h. it gonna gave you 'module object is not callable'

Comment: @Arun ERROR: No matching distribution found for urllib2. are you sure?

Comment: @greendino I meant `urllib.request` instead of `urllib(2)`, so `urllib.request.urlopen`. Also make sure to `import urllib.request` and not just `import urllib`.

Answer (score 22):

Use the requests library, pretty print the results so you can better locate the keys/values you want to extract, and then use nested for loops to parse the data. In the example I extract step by step driving directions.

```
import json, requests, pprint

url = 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?'

params = dict(
    origin='Chicago,IL',
    destination='Los+Angeles,CA',
    waypoints='Joplin,MO|Oklahoma+City,OK',
    sensor='false'
)


data = requests.get(url=url, params=params)
binary = data.content
output = json.loads(binary)

# test to see if the request was valid
#print output['status']

# output all of the results
#pprint.pprint(output)

# step-by-step directions
for route in output['routes']:
        for leg in route['legs']:
            for step in leg['steps']:
                print step['html_instructions']
```

Comment: Michael, how can I make some sense out of this once I got the data? How do I display it in "classic" json visual format (like the one you get in your browser)? Here is what I get in my terminal: [link]http://s13.postimg.org/3r55jajk7/terminal.png

Comment: @AlexStarbuck

`import pprint` then -> `pprint.pprint(step['html_instructions'])`

Answer (score 13):

just `import requests` and use from `json()` method :

```
source = requests.get("url").json()
print(source)
```

OR you can use this :

```
import json,urllib.request
data = urllib.request.urlopen("url").read()
output = json.loads(data)
print (output)
```

Comment: do i need to use something like data.close() after the code? or the request gets closed automatically after the url has been called.

Answer (score 11):

Try this:

```
import requests
import json

# Goole Maps API.
link = 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=Chicago,IL&destination=Los+Angeles,CA&waypoints=Joplin,MO|Oklahoma+City,OK&sensor=false'

# Request data from link as 'str'
data = requests.get(link).text

# convert 'str' to Json
data = json.loads(data)

# Now you can access Json 
for i in data['routes'][0]['legs'][0]['steps']:
    lattitude = i['start_location']['lat']
    longitude = i['start_location']['lng']
    print('{}, {}'.format(lattitude, longitude))
```

Answer (score 4):

Also for pretty Json on console:

```
import json     
json.dumps(response.json(), indent=2)
```

possible to use dumps with indent. (Please **import json**)