# Python requests - extracting data from response.text

Tags: python, json, python-requests

I have been looking around for a few days now and cannot figure this out. Basically I'm uploading an image to a server and get an ID in return, the problem is I cannot figure out how to extract this ID and change it into a String ready to be saved into a database.

Program Code

```
url = <Server address>
with open("image.jpg", "rb") as image_file:
    files = {'file': image_file}
    auth = ('<Key>', '<Pass>')
    r = requests.post(url, files=files, auth=auth)

data = r.json()
uploaded = data.get('uploaded')
content_id = uploaded[0]


print r
print r.text
print '--------------'
print str(content_id)
```

And here is the output I get

```
<Response [200]>
{
    "status": "success",
    "uploaded": [
        {
            "filename": "image.jpg",
            "id": "6476edfa1d262ad81181d992da78149d"
        }
     ]
}

--------------
{u'id': u'6476edfa1d262ad81181d992da78149d', u'filename': u'image.jpg'}
```

Comment: `content_id['id']` ?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You are receiving JSON; you already use the `response.json()` method to decode that to a Python structure:

```
data = r.json()
```

You can treat `data['uploaded']` as any other Python list; the content is just the one dictionary, so another dictionary key to get the `id` value:

```
data['uploaded'][0]['id']
```

It is safe to hardcode the index to `[0]` here as you know how many images you uploaded.

You could use exception handling to detect if anything unexpected was returned:

```
try:
    image_id = data['uploaded'][0]['id']
except (IndexError, KeyError):
    # key or index is missing, handle an unexpected response
    log.error('Unexpected response after uploading image, got %r',
              data)
```

or you could handle `data['status']`; it all depends on the exact semantics of the API you are using here.

Comment: It really surprised me, why is there in python so similarity between the objects and the asociative maps. You _won_, triage-steward! :-)