# Selecting values from a JSON file in Python

Tags: python, json

I am getting JIRA data using the following python code,

how do I store the response for more than one key (my example shows only one KEY but in general I get lot of data) and print **only** the values corresponding to `total,key, customfield_12830, summary`

```
    import requests
    import json
    import logging
    import datetime
    import base64
    import urllib
    serverURL = 'https://jira-stability-tools.company.com/jira'
    user = 'username'
    password = 'password'
    query = 'project = PROJECTNAME AND "Build Info" ~ BUILDNAME  AND assignee=ASSIGNEENAME'
    jql = '/rest/api/2/search?jql=%s' % urllib.quote(query)
    response = requests.get(serverURL + jql,verify=False,auth=(user, password))
    print response.json()
```

`response.json()` OUTPUT:-

http://pastebin.com/h8R4QMgB

Comment: If the structure you trimmed here to show only one item differs from the structure you need to support with more than one item, then any answer we give you is liable not to be useful in the other scenario.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28069753/python-requests-extracting-data-from-response-text related quetion. check it out too.

Comment: BTW, in general, if you have deeply nested structure (like this one!) that you want to figure out, `pprint` is your friend. See https://docs.python.org/2/library/pprint.html

Comment: Charles - is there an external link I can paste my sample output for more than item and share here?

Comment: Any ad-free pastebin ("ad-free" meaning "not pastebin.com") will do, but to be a good SO question, something needs to be useful and answerable even if external links break, so relying on even a good pastebin like https://gist.github.com/ or http://ix.io/ for essential as opposed to supplemental elements isn't ideal. Frankly, it would do a lot of good if you could summarize the structure -- taking out contents that aren't necessary to generate a minimal equivalent. Barring that, at least you could describe it -- is it a *list* containing items akin to what you showed, one per?

Comment: Charles - http://pastebin.com/h8R4QMgB is the link for 4 items,sorry the data is so huge to filter

Comment: @PythonProg, ...you may note that pastebin.com is the one pastebin I asked you *not* to use -- it's full of ads for anyone not using AdBlock or similar.

Comment: @ Charles Duffy - why dont you point to one pastebin that you recommend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the the link you pasted to pastebin and from the json that I saw, its a you `issues` as list containing `key, fields(which holds custom fields), self, id, expand`.

You can simply iterate through this response and extract values for keys you want. You can go like.

```
data = response.json()
issues = data.get('issues', list())

x = list()

for issue in issues:
    temp = {
        'key': issue['key'],
        'customfield': issue['fields']['customfield_12830'],
        'total': issue['fields']['progress']['total']
    }
    x.append(temp)
print(x)
```

**x** is list of dictionaries containing the data for fields you mentioned. Let me know if I have been unclear somewhere or what I have given is not what you are looking for.

**PS:** It is always advisable to use **dict.get('keyname', None)** to get  values as you can always put a default value if key is not found. For this solution I didn't do it as I just wanted to provide approach.

**Update**: In the comments you(OP) mentioned that it gives attributerror.Try this code

```
data = response.json()
issues = data.get('issues', list())

x = list()

for issue in issues:
    temp = dict()
    key = issue.get('key', None)
    if key:
       temp['key'] = key 

    fields = issue.get('fields', None)
    if fields:
        customfield = fields.get('customfield_12830', None)
        temp['customfield'] = customfield

        progress = fields.get('progress', None)
        if progress:
            total = progress.get('total', None)
            temp['total'] = total

    x.append(temp)
print(x)
```

Comment: this gives an error `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'`

Comment: am using Python 2.7.3,does it work for this version,it throws as error as I stated above

Comment: Thats the reason I mentioned that use, dict.get('keyname', None) to ensure that the key which you are trying to access indeed exists. For you this error is raised when you are trying to access either 'fields'  whose value is dictionary again or may be 'progress' which again is dictionary. To avoid it use fields = issue.get('fields', None). Then if fields then try to access your customfield within it

Comment: `data = response.json().get('data')` itself prints None where as `data = response.json()` prints the correct data,what is get('data') doing

Comment: Oh that, I did that out of habit, updated the answer, check it.

Comment: The piece of code after Update block is more fault tolerant. Hope it solves your problem smoothly.

Comment: Rajesh - did you use any tools to decipher this structure?what do you suggest for a beginner to understand this structure and had to do it himself?

Comment: Oh no tools just copy pasted your whole structure pasted it in my Sublime Text editor, set syntax to javascript  and pressed CTRL+ALT+F to format it to understandable json. Although I have this plugin Javascript Beautify installed in my Sublime Text. It helps a lot. :)

Comment: I read your second comment about python version now. This Python 3, but only print(x) should be changed to print x

Comment: @PythonProg, ...I also did previously suggest `pprint` as a tool to decipher the structure once it's in the Python world. On the JSON end, `jq` or just `python -m json.tool` will often suffice.