# How to read data from REST API and insert data in to MongoDB using Python?

Tags: python-3.x, mongodb, mongodb-query

How to read data from the REST API and insert that fetched data into MongoDB? I know that we can read REST API data using requests library and obtain the output. But how to insert the obtained output into MongoDB using python?

```
import requests

url='http://climatedataapi.worldbank.org/climateweb/rest/v1/country/cru/tas/year/CAN.csv'

response = requests.get(url)

if response.status_code != 200:
    print('Failed to get data:', response.status_code)
else:
    print('First 100 characters of data are')
    print(response.text[:100])
```

when I run this code I get the below output:

```
First 100 characters of data are
year,data
1901,-7.67241907119751
1902,-7.862711429595947
1903,-7.910782814025879
1904,-8.15572929382
```

Instead of printing, I want to insert in to mongodb. for this should I have to store the output in a file and then insert it to mongodb? if so, how to do?

Comment: your question is too broad, please, be more specific, add your code snippet with actual REST API you are struggling with

Comment: You can use ``requests`` module to read a REST API and write to MongoDB with ``pymongo``.

Comment: i have added the code snipet @AzatIbrakov

Comment: how to write to MongoDB with pymongo @RamazanPolat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope this helps, Let me know if you have any issues,

```
# *-* coding: utf-8 *-*

import requests

try:
    from pymongo import MongoClient
except ImportError:
    raise ImportError('PyMongo is not installed')


class MongoDB(object):
    def __init__(self, host='localhost', port=27017, database_name=None, collection_name=None):
        try:
            self._connection = MongoClient(host=host, port=port, maxPoolSize=200)
        except Exception as error:
            raise Exception(error)
        self._database = None
        self._collection = None
        if database_name:
            self._database = self._connection[database_name]
        if collection_name:
            self._collection = self._database[collection_name]

    def insert(self, post):
        # add/append/new single record
        post_id = self._collection.insert_one(post).inserted_id
        return post_id


url = 'http://climatedataapi.worldbank.org/climateweb/rest/v1/country/cru/tas/year/CAN.csv'
response = requests.get(url)
data = response.text
if response.status_code != 200:
    print('Failed to get data:', response.status_code)
else:
    print('First 100 characters of data are')
    print(data[:100])

print('[*] Parsing response text')
data = data.split('\n')
data_list = list()
for value in data:
    if 'year,data' not in value:
        if value:
            value = value.split(',')
            data_list.append({'year': int(value[0]), 'data': float(value[1])})

print(data_list)

print('[*] Pushing data to MongoDB ')
mongo_db = MongoDB(database_name='Climate_DB', collection_name='climate_data')

for collection in data_list:
    print('[!] Inserting - ', collection)
    mongo_db.insert(collection)
```

Output -

```
First 100 characters of data are
year,data
1901,-7.67241907119751
1902,-7.862711429595947
1903,-7.910782814025879
1904,-8.15572929382
[*] Parsing response text
[{'year': 1901, 'data': -7.67241907119751}, {'year': 1902, 'data': -7.862711429595947}, {'year': 1903, 'data': -7.910782814025879}, {'year': 1904, 'data': -8.155729293823242}, {'year': 1905, 'data': -7.547311305999756}, {'year': 1906, 'data': -7.684103488922119}, {'year': 1907, 'data': -8.413553237915039}, {'year': 1908, 'data': -7.790929317474365}, {'year': 1909, 'data': -8.23930549621582}, {'year': 1910, 'data': -7.774611473083496}, {'year': 1911, 'data': -8.114446640014648}, {'year': 1912, 'data': -7.885402679443359}, {'year': 1913, 'data': -7.987940311431885}, {'year': 1914, 'data': -7.965937614440918}]
[*] Pushing data to MongoDB 
[!] Inserting -  {'year': 1901, 'data': -7.67241907119751}
[!] Inserting -  {'year': 1902, 'data': -7.862711429595947}
[!] Inserting -  {'year': 1903, 'data': -7.910782814025879}
[!] Inserting -  {'year': 1904, 'data': -8.155729293823242}
[!] Inserting -  {'year': 1905, 'data': -7.547311305999756}
[!] Inserting -  {'year': 1906, 'data': -7.684103488922119}
```

Install requirements,

> pip install pymongo

MongoDB windows setup - 
https://gist.github.com/vijayanandrp/ddf72c2089015ee3f13be2b1a06bfd08

Answer (score 1):

You can grab the response as `json` through `requests`.

Tutorial: [HTTP requests and JSON parsing in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6386308/http-requests-and-json-parsing-in-python)

Then it's just a matter of inserting the stuff you want as a document into mondoDB. You'll need a client for that; `pymongo` is a pretty good bet.

Tutorial: http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/tutorial.html

Comment: thank you!! but i dint get how to insert it to the mongodb. Could u please share some code snippets. i have added the code snippet above. @nz_21