# JQuery post to flask causes TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, jquery, flask

with python3 and flask 1.0.3 I have created this method

```
@app.route("/robota/api/eye/left", methods=['POST'])
def move_eye():
   t = request.json['left']
   return 'test'
```

with JQuery I have created that function

```
    function move_eye(left){
        console.log(left);
        $.post(url + '/eye/left', left).done(function(leftEye) { showMyPositions(leftEye); });
    };
```

Which causes this output on the browser,

```
{posYaw: 53, posPitch: 37}

jquery.js:10254 POST http://localhost:8080/robota/api/eye/left 500
```

and this is returned by flask,

```
t = request.json['left']
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

I have mentioed the version as it seems flask changed over time the json handling
what would be the correct way to recieve the JQuery posted json on the flask side ?

Comment: Use `json()` instead of `json[]`. And check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17517598/8353711)

Comment: what data are you posting to flask please add that as well.

Comment: @shaik thanks  I did so. see the eample below, still no good result

Comment: I am posting json. print(request.is_json) returns true but when accessing it by content = request.get_json() I get a bad request return from flask