# how to convert http request to json or dict or some form of data with python3

Tags: python-3.x, http

how can i convert:

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:76.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/76.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: keep-alive
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
```

to something like

```py
_dict = {
"REQUEST": "/",
"HOST": "localhost",
"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:76.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/76.0",
"Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8",
"Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.5",
"Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate",
"Connection": "keep-alive",
"Upgrade-Insecure-Requests": 1,
"GET":"",
"POST":""}
```

how could i do this with python 3.
I don't want to just make a request to a website I want to convert this text to a dictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the requests module

```
import requests

r = requests.get("https://www.google.com")
print(r.headers) # returns all the headers in dictionary form
```

** *EDIT* **

So since he wants to spit those requests which is string from his created server.
Here is the new code:

```
request = """GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:76.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/76.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: keep-alive
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1""".split('\n')

reqs = {}

for x in request:
    if "GET" in x:
        method, path, http = x.split(" ")
        reqs["REQUESTS"] = path
    else:
        key, val = x.split(": ")
        reqs[key] = val
```

**NOTE**
You can make a list for the http methods (so that it didn't only work on GET) and make a 'for in' range for checking if that http method is in the request

Comment: i don't want to make a request. I want to convert a request to a dict

Comment: you don't want to make a request  but you want to convert a request to a dict? what?

Comment: I'm creating a webserver i need to handle the browser request so i need to convert the request to dictionary so i can use the data.

Comment: How would i get the get data from the url like /?data=ps&data1=ps1

Answer (score 1):

Checkout the following link. Its another Stackoverflow post, which should help you out :D

[HTTP requests and JSON parsing in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6386308/http-requests-and-json-parsing-in-python)

```
>>> import requests
>>> r = requests.get('https://github.com/timeline.json')
>>> r.json()
[{u'repository': {u'open_issues': 0, u'url': 'https://github.com/...
```