# similar sentence with python like bash with jq

Tags: python, json, jq

I'm trying to traslate shell script bash to pyhton.
I use jq to extract fileds of json response but with jsonresponse I can't do it with python.
Someone knows?
My bash line

```
jq -r '.search_objects[].price' file
```

I'm trying with

```
print(jsonResponse["search_objects"]["price"])
```

But fails :-(

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this

[HTTP requests and JSON parsing in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6386308/http-requests-and-json-parsing-in-python)

```
import json

data = json.loads(jsonResponse)
```

Comment: Other error occurred: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not dict