# Replace single quotes in a string but not escaped single quotes

Tags: python, json, python-requests, python-re

I'm making a Python API get request and getting JSON results which I have captured in a string. The string is similar to a string literal containing a dictionary: `{'key1': 4, 'key2': 'I\'m home'}`. I need to format it to a string literal containing a proper JSON object like this: `{"key1": 4, "key2": "I\'m home"}`, so that I can save to a JSON file.

To achieve this, I tried using regular expressions with [negative look-ahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to replace all the single quotes (except the escaped single quote) like this:

```
import re

#.... other codes
str = re.sub("'(!?\')", "\"", result) # result = "{'key1': 4, 'key2': 'I\'m home'}"
print (str)
```

But I get this output

```
{"key1": 4, "key2": "I"m home"}
```

instead of

```
{"key1": 4, "key2": "I\'m home"}
```

How do I create the regular expression, so that escaped single quotes `\'` are preserved and all others are replaced with double-quotes.

Comment: So you are getting JSON results that aren't JSON?

Comment: ```result = requests.get(url).json()```. I'm getting results from a Python ```requests.get()``` object method and the method is named ```json()```. But result is returned with keys in single quote, which Visual Studio code is reporting as not a proper json when I copy it to a json file.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [HTTP requests and JSON parsing in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6386308/http-requests-and-json-parsing-in-python)

Comment: It seems you do not have to do anything, `requests.get(url).json()` already decodes the JSON and returns a Python data structure.

Comment: You can *encode* it back to a JSON string by using `import json; json.dumps(result)`, if that's what you want. Or you can skip the decoding and return the JSON string directly, by using [`requests.get(url).raw`](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/quickstart/#raw-response-content) instead.

Comment: @mkrieger1, I've just tried that on my machine. result is still dumped with keys in single quote. *I want keys in double quote*

Comment: `"{'key1': 4, 'key2': 'I\'m home'}"` does _not_ have a backslash: `\'` is simply a `'`. `"{'key1': 4, 'key2': 'I\\'m home'}"` _does_ have a backslash. Which one do you actually have?

Comment: @DYZ it's the former. I want to keep track of the "history of manipulations" done on the data, that is the reason I'm capturing it to a string. I'm aware ```I\'m``` will  display as ```I'm``` when sent to the display.  But your answer gets it right in a way. I'll have to escape all backslashes before using the negative lookbehind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a negative lookbehind, not a negative lookahead ("no backslash before a quote"):

```
result = '''{'key1': 4, 'key2': 'I\\'m home'}'''
print(re.sub(r"(?<!\\)'", '"', result))
#{"key1": 4, "key2": "I\'m home"}
```

Comment: This is not still working for me. I'm still getting  ```{"key1": 4, "key2": "I"m home"}```. I just tried it on my machine.

Comment: Your answer gets it right in a way. I'll have to escape all backslashes before using the negative lookbehind.