# jq - group json objects by field value and output grouped values in one line

Tags: json, linux, group-by, jq, amazon-cloudwatch

I have a json format with metrics & timestamps & values ​​from AWS Cloudwatch.

```
{
    "Messages": [],
    "MetricDataResults": [
        {
            "Timestamps": [
                "2021-07-07T13:26:00Z"
            ],
            "StatusCode": "Complete",
            "Values": [
                0.0
            ],
            "Id": "m19",
            "Label": "CPUSurplusCreditsCharged"
        },
        {
            "Timestamps": [
                "2021-07-07T13:28:00Z",
                "2021-07-07T13:27:00Z",
                "2021-07-07T13:26:00Z",
                "2021-07-07T13:25:00Z",
                "2021-07-07T13:24:00Z",
                "2021-07-07T13:23:00Z"
            ],
            "StatusCode": "Complete",
            "Values": [
                12.750425014167137,
                13.033116114731422,
                12.70812153130781,
                12.975,
                15.441924032067199,
                12.916451392476791
            ],
            "Id": "m20",
            "Label": "CPUUtilization"
        },
        {
            "Timestamps": [
                "2021-07-07T13:29:00Z",
                "2021-07-07T13:28:00Z",
                "2021-07-07T13:27:00Z",
                "2021-07-07T13:26:00Z",
                "2021-07-07T13:25:00Z",
                "2021-07-07T13:24:00Z",
                "2021-07-07T13:23:00Z"
            ],
            "StatusCode": "Complete",
            "Values": [
                0.7,
                0.6999533364442371,
                0.6998833527745376,
                0.6999416715273727,
                0.7,
                0.7001166861143524,
                0.6998950157476379
            ],
            "Id": "m21",
            "Label": "NetworkReceiveThroughput"
        }
    ]
}
```

I put these values ​​in an array variable using the jq command.
And the result is output to the array variable as follows.

```
jq -r '.MetricDataResults[] | "\(.Label) \(.Timestamps) \(.Values)"' test.json | while read Label timestamp value
do

  Label=`echo $Label | sed 's/\"//g; s/\[//g; s/\]//g; s/,/ /g'`
  timestamp=`echo $timestamp | sed 's/\"//g; s/\[//g; s/\]//g; s/,/ /g'`
  value=`echo $value | sed 's/\"//g; s/\[//g; s/\]//g; s/,/ /g'`

  arr_timestamp=($timestamp)
  arr_value=($value)

  echo $Label
  echo ${arr_timestamp[@]}
  echo ${arr_value[@]}
done



Evictions
2021-07-07T10:51:00Z 2021-07-07T10:50:00Z 2021-07-07T10:49:00Z 2021-07-07T10:48:00Z 2021-07-07T10:47:00Z 2021-07-07T10:46:00Z 2021-07-07T10:45:00Z
0 0 0 0 0 0 0

CPUUtilization
2021-07-07T10:50:00Z 2021-07-07T10:49:00Z 2021-07-07T10:48:00Z 2021-07-07T10:47:00Z 2021-07-07T10:46:00Z 2021-07-07T10:45:00Z
1.5333333333333332 1.4666666666666666 1.5833333333333333 1.5333333333333332 1.4916666666666665 1.4916666666666665

IsMaster
2021-07-07T10:51:00Z 2021-07-07T10:50:00Z 2021-07-07T10:49:00Z 2021-07-07T10:48:00Z 2021-07-07T10:47:00Z 2021-07-07T10:46:00Z 2021-07-07T10:45:00Z
1 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

When timestamp is not the same length for each array variable,
I want to display only values ​​in the same timestamp as a single string.

For example

```
"2021-07-07T10:51:00Z Evictions = 0\nIsMaster = 1"
"2021-07-07T10:50:00Z Evictions = 0\nCPUUtilization = 1.5333333333333332\n IsMaster = 1"
...
```

My head is bad and I can't think of a good way. 
Please let me know if there is any good way.
I don't have much time so please help on stackoverflow.

- Add
  I mean group by Timestamps. Like this

```
{
    "MetricDataResults": [
        {
            "Timestamps": "2021-07-07T13:28:00Z",
            "Label" : [
               "CPUUtilization",
               "NetworkReceiveThroughput"
            ],
            "Values" : [
               12.750425014167137,
               0.7
            ]
         },
         {
            "Timestamps": "2021-07-07T13:27:00Z",
            "Label" : [
               "CPUUtilization",
               "NetworkReceiveThroughput"
            ],
            "Values" : [
               13.033116114731422,
               0.6999533364442371
            ]
         },
         {
            "Timestamps": "2021-07-07T13:26:00Z",
            "Label" : [
               "CPUUtilization",
               "NetworkReceiveThroughput",
               "CPUSurplusCreditsCharged"
            ],
            "Values" : [
               12.70812153130781,
               0.6998833527745376,
               0.0
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: use some general purpose programming language?

Comment: I use only shell script.

Comment: Could you recommend other useful programming ?

Comment: i personally prefer python or perl(it is said perl is very powerful text extraction tool)

Comment: Yup, I would say that pythons `json` and `requests` modules are more suited and easy to maintain , take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6386308/http-requests-and-json-parsing-in-python

Comment: The task could be easily achieved using jq without messing around with shell variables, shell arrays, or sed, but your specific requirements are unclear to me.  If you showed the complete expected output it would help.

Comment: @peak  Below the text I have written the desired result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a simple, idiomatic solution for the case of text output; it can be used with any version of jq from 1.3 onwards.  Note in particular that it does not rely on `foreach`, the use of which here is overly complicated:

```
< input.json jq -r '
  .MetricDataResults
  | map(.Values as $values
        | .Timestamps as $timestamps
        | {Label} +
           (range(0; .Timestamps|length) as $idx
            | {Timestamp: $timestamps[$idx], 
               Value:     $values[$idx]} ))
  | group_by(.Timestamp)[]
  | .[0].Timestamp, (.[]|"\(.Label)=\(.Value)"), ""
'
```

Comment: I thought about a `foreach`-free solution but didn't come up with it. Thank you for showing how to do it !

Comment: @jpseng - And thanks for making some sense of the Q :-)

Answer (score 4):

You can achieve your goal just using `jq`. Further processing by shell scripting is not necessary.
The following shell script gives you two alternatives:

- output as text
- output as json

```sh
#!/bin/bash

INPUT='
{
    "Messages": [],
    "MetricDataResults": [
        {
            "Timestamps": [
                "2021-07-07T13:26:00Z"
            ],
            "StatusCode": "Complete",
            "Values": [
                0.0
            ],
            "Id": "m19",
            "Label": "CPUSurplusCreditsCharged"
        },
        {
            "Timestamps": [
                "2021-07-07T13:28:00Z",
                "2021-07-07T13:27:00Z",
                "2021-07-07T13:26:00Z",
                "2021-07-07T13:25:00Z",
                "2021-07-07T13:24:00Z",
                "2021-07-07T13:23:00Z"
            ],
            "StatusCode": "Complete",
            "Values": [
                12.750425014167137,
                13.033116114731422,
                12.70812153130781,
                12.975,
                15.441924032067199,
                12.916451392476791
            ],
            "Id": "m20",
            "Label": "CPUUtilization"
        },
        {
            "Timestamps": [
                "2021-07-07T13:29:00Z",
                "2021-07-07T13:28:00Z",
                "2021-07-07T13:27:00Z",
                "2021-07-07T13:26:00Z",
                "2021-07-07T13:25:00Z",
                "2021-07-07T13:24:00Z",
                "2021-07-07T13:23:00Z"
            ],
            "StatusCode": "Complete",
            "Values": [
                0.7,
                0.6999533364442371,
                0.6998833527745376,
                0.6999416715273727,
                0.7,
                0.7001166861143524,
                0.6998950157476379
            ],
            "Id": "m21",
            "Label": "NetworkReceiveThroughput"
        }
    ]
}
'

# output as plain text
jq -r '
  .MetricDataResults
  | map(.Values as $values | .Timestamps as $timestamps
        | {Label} +
          foreach range(.Timestamps | length) as $idx
                  (null; {"Timestamp": $timestamps[$idx], "Value": $values[$idx]}; .))
  | group_by(.Timestamp)[]
  | [.[0].Timestamp]
    + map("\(.Label)=\(.Value)")
    | join("\n") + "\n"
' <<< "$INPUT"

# output as json
jq -r '
  .MetricDataResults
  |= (map(.Values as $values | .Timestamps as $timestamps
          | {Id, Label, StatusCode} +
            foreach range(.Timestamps | length) as $idx
                    (null; {"Timestamp": $timestamps[$idx], "Value": $values[$idx]}; .))
     | group_by(.Timestamp)
     | map({Timestamp: .[0].Timestamp,
            Events: del(.[].Timestamp)}))
' <<< "$INPUT"
```

---

The first `jq` command of the shell script produces:

```
2021-07-07T13:23:00Z
CPUUtilization=12.916451392476791
NetworkReceiveThroughput=0.6998950157476379

2021-07-07T13:24:00Z
CPUUtilization=15.441924032067199
NetworkReceiveThroughput=0.7001166861143524

2021-07-07T13:25:00Z
CPUUtilization=12.975
NetworkReceiveThroughput=0.7

2021-07-07T13:26:00Z
CPUSurplusCreditsCharged=0
CPUUtilization=12.70812153130781
NetworkReceiveThroughput=0.6999416715273727

2021-07-07T13:27:00Z
CPUUtilization=13.033116114731422
NetworkReceiveThroughput=0.6998833527745376

2021-07-07T13:28:00Z
CPUUtilization=12.750425014167137
NetworkReceiveThroughput=0.6999533364442371

2021-07-07T13:29:00Z
NetworkReceiveThroughput=0.7
```

---

The second `jq` command of the shell script produces:

```json
{
  "Messages": [],
  "MetricDataResults": [
    {
      "Timestamp": "2021-07-07T13:23:00Z",
      "Events": [
        {
          "Id": "m20",
          "Label": "CPUUtilization",
          "StatusCode": "Complete",
          "Value": 12.916451392476791
        },
        {
          "Id": "m21",
          "Label": "NetworkReceiveThroughput",
          "StatusCode": "Complete",
          "Value": 0.6998950157476379
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "Timestamp": "2021-07-07T13:24:00Z",
      "Events": [
        {
          "Id": "m20",
          "Label": "CPUUtilization",
          "StatusCode": "Complete",
          "Value": 15.441924032067199
        },
        {
          "Id": "m21",
          "Label": "NetworkReceiveThroughput",
          "StatusCode": "Complete",
          "Value": 0.7001166861143524
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "Timestamp": "2021-07-07T13:25:00Z",
      "Events": [
        {
          "Id": "m20",
          "Label": "CPUUtilization",
          "StatusCode": "Complete",
          "Value": 12.975
        },
        {
          "Id": "m21",
          "Label": "NetworkReceiveThroughput",
          "StatusCode": "Complete",
          "Value": 0.7
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "Timestamp": "2021-07-07T13:26:00Z",
      "Events": [
        {
          "Id": "m19",
          "Label": "CPUSurplusCreditsCharged",
          "StatusCode": "Complete",
          "Value": 0
        },
        {
          "Id": "m20",
          "Label": "CPUUtilization",
          "StatusCode": "Complete",
          "Value": 12.70812153130781
        },
        {
          "Id": "m21",
          "Label": "NetworkReceiveThroughput",
          "StatusCode": "Complete",
          "Value": 0.6999416715273727
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "Timestamp": "2021-07-07T13:27:00Z",
      "Events": [
        {
          "Id": "m20",
          "Label": "CPUUtilization",
          "StatusCode": "Complete",
          "Value": 13.033116114731422
        },
        {
          "Id": "m21",
          "Label": "NetworkReceiveThroughput",
          "StatusCode": "Complete",
          "Value": 0.6998833527745376
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "Timestamp": "2021-07-07T13:28:00Z",
      "Events": [
        {
          "Id": "m20",
          "Label": "CPUUtilization",
          "StatusCode": "Complete",
          "Value": 12.750425014167137
        },
        {
          "Id": "m21",
          "Label": "NetworkReceiveThroughput",
          "StatusCode": "Complete",
          "Value": 0.6999533364442371
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "Timestamp": "2021-07-07T13:29:00Z",
      "Events": [
        {
          "Id": "m21",
          "Label": "NetworkReceiveThroughput",
          "StatusCode": "Complete",
          "Value": 0.7
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thank you.. Thank you so much.<br/>
I ran your first jq command.
The result is an error.. May I know if you executed it from a shell script file?<br/>
error message```error: syntax error, unexpected IDENT```

Comment: And I execute in shell file ```jq -r '
  .MetricDataResults
  |= (map(.Values as $values
          | .Timestamps as $timestamps
          | {Id, Label, StatusCode} +
            foreach range(.Timestamps | length) as $idx
                    (null; {"Timestamp": $timestamps[$idx], "Value": $values[$idx]}; .))
     | group_by(.Timestamp)
     | map({Timestamp: .[0].Timestamp, Events:. | del(.[] | .Timestamp)}))
' sh-test-001.json
```

Comment: And this.. ```jq -r '.MetricDataResults | map(.Values as '$values' | .Timestamps as '$timestamps' | {Id, Label, StatusCode} + foreach range(.Timestamps | length) as '$idx' (null; {"Timestamp": '$timestamps[$idx]', "Value": '$values[$idx]'}; .)) | group_by(.Timestamp)[] | [.[0].Timestamp] + map("\(.Label)=\(.Value)") | join("\n") + "\n"' sh-test-001.json```

Comment: Ohhhh.  sorry sir... My jq version was 1.4, I upgraded it to 1.6 and succeeded. Thank you so much.

Comment: I posted the complete shell script in the answer

Comment: Yes. You are right.  This problem was caused by my jq version being low. Thank you.