# How to get json from <class 'requests.models.Response'>

Tags: python, json, python-requests

```
url = cmsServiceBaseUrl
resp = requests.get(url,json=cmsServiceRequestBaseFormat)
return resp.get("data")
```

The resp type is `<class 'requests.models.Response'>` but I want json

Comment: requests library has json method. Just use resp.json()

Comment: Does this answer your question? [HTTP requests and JSON parsing in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6386308/http-requests-and-json-parsing-in-python)

Answer (score 1):

You need to call `resp.json()`.

The response will be a JSON parsed into a dictionary or a list of dictionaries.

Here is an example from the [docs](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/):

```
>>> import requests

>>> r = requests.get('https://api.github.com/events')
>>> r.json()
[{'repository': {'open_issues': 0, 'url': 'https://github.com/...
```

Comment: Now it is converting in <class 'dict'> form not in json

Comment: The `json()` method returns a **parsed** JSON. In Python you can either get the JSON data as a raw string or parsed into some Python object.

Answer (score 0):

You can get a json from the response like this

```
url=cmsServiceBaseUrl
resp=requests.get(url,json=cmsServiceRequestBaseFormat)
return resp.json()
```

Here is the related doc from requests: https://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#json-response-content