# Python, how to indent and filter for JSON of REST-API response

Tags: python, json, rest, indexing, filter

This is my python code

```
import requests

response = requests.get('https://api.open-meteo.com/v1/forecast?latitude=52.52&longitude=13.41&hourly=temperature_2m,relativehumidity_2m,windspeed_10m')

print(response.content)
```

I got this result

```
b'{"latitude":52.52,"longitude":13.419998,"generationtime_ms":0.48100948333740234,"utc_offset_seconds":0,"timezone":"GMT","timezone_abbreviation":"GMT","elevation":38.0,"hourly_units":{"time":"iso8601","temperature_2m":"\xc2\xb0C","relativehumidity_2m":"%","windspeed_10m":"km/h"},"hourly":{"time":["2022-09-26T00:00","2022-09-26T01:00","2022-09-26T02:00","2022-09-26T03:00","2022-09-26T04:00","2022-09-26T05:00","2022-09-26T06:00","2022-09-26T07:00","2022-09-26T08:00","2022-09-26T09:00","2022-09-26T10:00","2022-09-26T11:00","2022-09-26T12:00","2022-09-26T13:00","2022-09-26T14:00","2022-09-26T15:00","2022-09-26T16:00","2022-09-26T17:00","2022-09-26T18:00","2022-09-26T19:00","2022-09-26T20:00","2022-09-26T21:00","2022-09-26T22:00","2022-09-26T23:00","2022-09-27T00:00","2022-09-27T01:00","2022-09-27T02:00","2022-09-27T03:00","2022-09-27T04:00","2022-09-27T05:00","2022-09-27T06:00","2022-09-27T07:00","2022-09-27T08:00","2022-09-27T09:00","2022-09-27T10:00","2022-09-27T11:00","2022-09-27T12:00","2022-09-27T13:00","2022-09-27T14:00","2022-09-27T15:00","2022-09-27T16:00","2022-09-27T17:00","2022-09-27T18:00","2022-09-27T19:00","2022-09-27T20:00","2022-09-27T21:00","2022-09-27T22:00","2022-09-27T23:00","2022-09-28T00:00","2022-09-28T01:00","2022-09-28T02:00","2022-09-28T03:00","2022-09-28T04:00","2022-09-28T05:00","2022-09-28T06:00","2022-09-28T07:00","2022-09-28T08:00","2022-09-28T09:00","2022-09-28T10:00","2022-09-28T11:00","2022-09-28T12:00","2022-09-28T13:00","2022-09-28T14:00","2022-09-28T15:00","2022-09-28T16:00","2022-09-28T17:00","2022-09-28T18:00","2022-09-28T19:00","2022-09-28T20:00","2022-09-28T21:00","2022-09-28T22:00","2022-09-28T23:00","2022-09-29T00:00","2022-09-29T01:00","2022-09-29T02:00","2022-09-29T03:00","2022-09-29T04:00","2022-09-29T05:00","2022-09-29T06:00","2022-09-29T07:00","2022-09-29T08:00","2022-09-29T09:00","2022-09-29T10:00","2022-09-29T11:00","2022-09-29T12:00","2022-09-29T13:00","2022-09-29T14:00","2022-09-29T15:00","2022-09-29T16:00","2022-09-29T17:00","2022-09-29T18:00","2022-09-29T19:00","2022-09-29T20:00","2022-09-29T21:00","2022-09-29T22:00","2022-09-29T23:00","2022-09-30T00:00","2022-09-30T01:00","2022-09-30T02:00","2022-09-30T03:00","2022-09-30T04:00","2022-09-30T05:00","2022-09-30T06:00","2022-09-30T07:00","2022-09-30T08:00","2022-09-30T09:00","2022-09-30T10:00","2022-09-30T11:00","2022-09-30T12:00","2022-09-30T13:00","2022-09-30T14:00","2022-09-30T15:00","2022-09-30T16:00","2022-09-30T17:00","2022-09-30T18:00","2022-09-30T19:00","2022-09-30T20:00","2022-09-30T21:00","2022-09-30T22:00","2022-09-30T23:00","2022-10-01T00:00","2022-10-01T01:00","2022-10-01T02:00","2022-10-01T03:00","2022-10-01T04:00","2022-10-01T05:00","2022-10-01T06:00","2022-10-01T07:00","2022-10-01T08:00","2022-10-01T09:00","2022-10-01T10:00","2022-10-01T11:00","2022-10-01T12:00","2022-10-01T13:00","2022-10-01T14:00","2022-10-01T15:00","2022-10-01T16:00","2022-10-01T17:00","2022-10-01T18:00","2022-10-01T19:00","2022-10-01T20:00","2022-10-01T21:00","2022-10-01T22:00","2022-10-01T23:00","2022-10-02T00:00","2022-10-02T01:00","2022-10-02T02:00","2022-10-02T03:00","2022-10-02T04:00","2022-10-02T05:00","2022-10-02T06:00","2022-10-02T07:00","2022-10-02T08:00","2022-10-02T09:00","2022-10-02T10:00","2022-10-02T11:00","2022-10-02T12:00","2022-10-02T13:00","2022-10-02T14:00","2022-10-02T15:00","2022-10-02T16:00","2022-10-02T17:00","2022-10-02T18:00","2022-10-02T19:00","2022-10-02T20:00","2022-10-02T21:00","2022-10-02T22:00","2022-10-02T23:00"],"temperature_2m":[11.7,11.4,11.0,10.7,10.0,9.7,10.2,11.3,13.0,14.6,15.8,17.0,17.0,17.4,17.3,16.8,16.3,15.5,14.4,13.5,12.9,12.7,12.4,12.0,11.7,11.6,11.5,11.4,11.2,10.9,10.7,11.0,11.4,12.2,12.8,12.9,12.1,12.6,12.7,12.0,11.4,11.0,10.1,9.7,9.4,9.2,8.9,8.4,8.0,7.8,7.9,8.1,8.0,8.0,7.8,8.1,9.3,10.5,11.2,11.2,11.2,10.8,10.4,10.5,10.8,10.1,9.3,8.7,8.0,7.2,6.2,5.9,5.7,5.3,4.9,4.6,4.6,4.4,4.7,6.4,8.8,10.9,12.7,13.6,13.9,14.4,14.4,14.0,13.6,12.6,11.1,10.3,9.6,8.7,8.1,7.6,7.1,6.8,6.6,6.3,6.0,5.7,6.0,7.5,9.6,12.2,13.6,14.7,15.8,16.2,16.3,16.0,15.2,14.1,12.6,11.8,11.1,10.2,9.7,9.3,8.7,8.3,7.8,7.3,6.8,6.3,6.6,8.1,10.3,13.0,14.5,15.8,17.0,16.7,15.7,14.3,13.6,13.0,12.4,12.0,11.6,11.3,11.3,11.4,11.5,11.5,11.5,11.4,11.3,11.1,11.1,11.7,12.6,13.4,13.2,12.6,12.2,12.6,13.3,14.0,14.0,13.7,13.3,12.9,12.6,12.1,11.9,11.8],"relativehumidity_2m":[88.0,90.0,90.0,90.0,93.0,95.0,93.0,84.0,74.0,67.0,53.0,45.0,47.0,47.0,44.0,47.0,47.0,52.0,58.0,65.0,68.0,74.0,73.0,75.0,76.0,76.0,75.0,76.0,78.0,81.0,85.0,85.0,83.0,77.0,75.0,70.0,77.0,74.0,75.0,74.0,78.0,77.0,81.0,87.0,86.0,83.0,89.0,93.0,94.0,93.0,94.0,94.0,94.0,92.0,89.0,85.0,77.0,69.0,63.0,64.0,63.0,69.0,73.0,73.0,69.0,74.0,78.0,80.0,83.0,87.0,92.0,92.0,93.0,94.0,94.0,94.0,94.0,93.0,92.0,84.0,76.0,69.0,61.0,53.0,52.0,50.0,51.0,54.0,55.0,59.0,68.0,73.0,78.0,83.0,85.0,87.0,88.0,89.0,90.0,90.0,91.0,91.0,89.0,83.0,74.0,63.0,57.0,53.0,48.0,46.0,44.0,45.0,49.0,55.0,62.0,65.0,68.0,71.0,73.0,74.0,76.0,78.0,79.0,81.0,83.0,84.0,83.0,77.0,69.0,59.0,55.0,53.0,51.0,52.0,57.0,64.0,69.0,74.0,80.0,83.0,86.0,88.0,88.0,88.0,87.0,87.0,86.0,86.0,86.0,87.0,86.0,82.0,77.0,73.0,77.0,83.0,90.0,89.0,87.0,83.0,82.0,82.0,82.0,81.0,80.0,80.0,80.0,81.0],"windspeed_10m":[9.7,8.2,6.6,5.1,5.1,5.1,5.4,7.8,10.2,11.9,11.8,13.5,13.4,13.8,14.6,17.1,12.1,11.4,10.4,10.6,10.5,9.8,9.7,9.1,10.0,11.0,11.9,13.2,11.9,12.3,12.3,12.5,12.4,15.2,14.4,14.8,15.4,13.2,15.9,13.9,14.0,14.4,7.2,5.5,6.6,7.5,7.3,6.3,5.2,4.5,5.2,5.4,5.5,6.5,6.0,7.3,7.2,7.9,8.4,9.1,8.2,9.2,5.1,3.3,5.2,2.5,1.5,1.1,0.7,3.3,3.1,3.4,3.1,3.2,3.6,3.7,3.7,3.7,3.8,4.0,5.1,6.2,8.1,10.1,11.4,10.8,11.8,10.6,8.7,5.4,6.7,6.5,6.2,6.1,6.1,5.9,5.6,5.7,5.5,5.6,5.3,4.7,4.6,5.1,5.6,6.9,8.2,9.3,10.5,10.6,10.0,8.7,7.1,5.1,4.1,4.7,5.4,6.5,6.9,6.8,6.8,6.5,6.2,5.7,5.5,5.8,6.0,6.5,7.4,8.3,9.7,12.7,16.1,16.7,16.3,15.0,14.5,13.9,13.0,12.7,12.7,12.9,12.7,12.6,12.3,12.9,13.8,14.5,14.0,13.0,12.1,11.9,12.2,12.8,12.9,12.3,11.7,10.4,10.5,12.2,13.7,15.1,16.6,17.0,17.5,17.3,16.5,15.7]}}'
```

I want to get this result

```
{
  "latitude": 52.52,
  "longitude": 13.419998,
  "generationtime_ms": 0.47206878662109375,
  "utc_offset_seconds": 0,
  "timezone": "GMT",
  "timezone_abbreviation": "GMT",
  "elevation": 38,
  "hourly_units": {
    "time": "iso8601",
    "temperature_2m": "°C",
    "relativehumidity_2m": "%",
    "windspeed_10m": "km/h"
  },
}
```

I have no idea how to get this result.
Someone help me? Thanks for your help.

Comment: response.json() is what you need

Comment: You can check this link too : [HTTP requests and JSON parsing in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6386308/http-requests-and-json-parsing-in-python)

Comment: What @ErnestBidouille said, or `import json; json.loads(response.content)`

Comment: AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'json'

Comment: it display but not ident

Comment: don't apply `response.content.json()` but `response.json()`

Comment: can you make answer with full source code?

Answer (score 0):

This is what you need. It format the content to JSON format.

```py
import requests

response = requests.get('https://api.open-meteo.com/v1/forecast?latitude=52.52&longitude=13.41&hourly=temperature_2m,relativehumidity_2m,windspeed_10m')

print(response.json())
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use response.json().

```
import requests
import json

response = requests.get('https://api.open-meteo.com/v1/forecast?latitude=52.52&longitude=13.41&hourly=temperature_2m,relativehumidity_2m,windspeed_10m')

print(json.dumps(response.json(), indent=4))
```

and the output will be json formatted and you can do whatever you want with it after:

```
{
   "latitude":52.52,
   "longitude":13.419998,
   "generationtime_ms":0.41306018829345703,
   "utc_offset_seconds":0,
   "timezone":"GMT",
   "timezone_abbreviation":"GMT",
   "elevation":38.0,
   "hourly_units":{
      "time":"iso8601",
      "temperature_2m":"°C",
      "relativehumidity_2m":"%",
      "windspeed_10m":"km/h"
   },
   "hourly":{
      "time":[
         "2022-09-26T00:00",
         "2022-09-26T01:00",
         "2022-09-26T02:00",
         "2022-09-26T03:00",
         "2022-09-26T04:00",
         "2022-09-26T05:00",
         "2022-09-26T06:00",
         "2022-09-26T07:00",
         "2022-09-26T08:00",
         "2022-09-26T09:00",
         "2022-09-26T10:00",
         "2022-09-26T11:00",
         "2022-09-26T12:00",
         "2022-09-26T13:00",
         "2022-09-26T14:00",
         "2022-09-26T15:00",
         "2022-09-26T16:00",
         "2022-09-26T17:00",
         "2022-09-26T18:00",
         "2022-09-26T19:00",
         "2022-09-26T20:00",
         "2022-09-26T21:00",
         "2022-09-26T22:00",
         "2022-09-26T23:00",
         "2022-09-27T00:00",
         "2022-09-27T01:00",
         "2022-09-27T02:00",
         "2022-09-27T03:00",
         "2022-09-27T04:00",
         "2022-09-27T05:00",
         "2022-09-27T06:00",
         "2022-09-27T07:00",
         "2022-09-27T08:00",
         "2022-09-27T09:00",
         "2022-09-27T10:00",
         "2022-09-27T11:00",
         "2022-09-27T12:00",
         "2022-09-27T13:00",
         "2022-09-27T14:00",
         "2022-09-27T15:00",
         "2022-09-27T16:00",
         "2022-09-27T17:00",
         "2022-09-27T18:00",
         "2022-09-27T19:00",
         "2022-09-27T20:00",
         "2022-09-27T21:00",
         "2022-09-27T22:00",
         "2022-09-27T23:00",
         "2022-09-28T00:00",
         "2022-09-28T01:00",
         "2022-09-28T02:00",
         "2022-09-28T03:00",
         "2022-09-28T04:00",
         "2022-09-28T05:00",
         "2022-09-28T06:00",
         "2022-09-28T07:00",
         "2022-09-28T08:00",
         "2022-09-28T09:00",
         "2022-09-28T10:00",
         "2022-09-28T11:00",
         "2022-09-28T12:00",
         "2022-09-28T13:00",
         "2022-09-28T14:00",
         "2022-09-28T15:00",
         "2022-09-28T16:00",
         "2022-09-28T17:00",
         "2022-09-28T18:00",
         "2022-09-28T19:00",
         "2022-09-28T20:00",
         "2022-09-28T21:00",
         "2022-09-28T22:00",
         "2022-09-28T23:00",
         "2022-09-29T00:00",
         "2022-09-29T01:00",
         "2022-09-29T02:00",
         "2022-09-29T03:00",
         "2022-09-29T04:00",
         "2022-09-29T05:00",
         "2022-09-29T06:00",
         "2022-09-29T07:00",
         "2022-09-29T08:00",
         "2022-09-29T09:00",
         "2022-09-29T10:00",
         "2022-09-29T11:00",
         "2022-09-29T12:00",
         "2022-09-29T13:00",
         "2022-09-29T14:00",
         "2022-09-29T15:00",
         "2022-09-29T16:00",
         "2022-09-29T17:00",
         "2022-09-29T18:00",
         "2022-09-29T19:00",
         "2022-09-29T20:00",
         "2022-09-29T21:00",
         "2022-09-29T22:00",
         "2022-09-29T23:00",
         "2022-09-30T00:00",
         "2022-09-30T01:00",
         "2022-09-30T02:00",
         "2022-09-30T03:00",
         "2022-09-30T04:00",
         "2022-09-30T05:00",
         "2022-09-30T06:00",
         "2022-09-30T07:00",
         "2022-09-30T08:00",
         "2022-09-30T09:00",
         "2022-09-30T10:00",
         "2022-09-30T11:00",
         "2022-09-30T12:00",
         "2022-09-30T13:00",
         "2022-09-30T14:00",
         "2022-09-30T15:00",
         "2022-09-30T16:00",
         "2022-09-30T17:00",
         "2022-09-30T18:00",
         "2022-09-30T19:00",
         "2022-09-30T20:00",
         "2022-09-30T21:00",
         "2022-09-30T22:00",
         "2022-09-30T23:00",
         "2022-10-01T00:00",
         "2022-10-01T01:00",
         "2022-10-01T02:00",
         "2022-10-01T03:00",
         "2022-10-01T04:00",
         "2022-10-01T05:00",
         "2022-10-01T06:00",
         "2022-10-01T07:00",
         "2022-10-01T08:00",
         "2022-10-01T09:00",
         "2022-10-01T10:00",
         "2022-10-01T11:00",
         "2022-10-01T12:00",
         "2022-10-01T13:00",
         "2022-10-01T14:00",
         "2022-10-01T15:00",
         "2022-10-01T16:00",
         "2022-10-01T17:00",
         "2022-10-01T18:00",
         "2022-10-01T19:00",
         "2022-10-01T20:00",
         "2022-10-01T21:00",
         "2022-10-01T22:00",
         "2022-10-01T23:00",
         "2022-10-02T00:00",
         "2022-10-02T01:00",
         "2022-10-02T02:00",
         "2022-10-02T03:00",
         "2022-10-02T04:00",
         "2022-10-02T05:00",
         "2022-10-02T06:00",
         "2022-10-02T07:00",
         "2022-10-02T08:00",
         "2022-10-02T09:00",
         "2022-10-02T10:00",
         "2022-10-02T11:00",
         "2022-10-02T12:00",
         "2022-10-02T13:00",
         "2022-10-02T14:00",
         "2022-10-02T15:00",
         "2022-10-02T16:00",
         "2022-10-02T17:00",
         "2022-10-02T18:00",
         "2022-10-02T19:00",
         "2022-10-02T20:00",
         "2022-10-02T21:00",
         "2022-10-02T22:00",
         "2022-10-02T23:00"
      ],
      "temperature_2m":[
         11.7,
         11.4,
         11.0,
         10.7,
         10.0,
         9.7,
         10.2,
         11.3,
         13.0,
         14.6,
         15.8,
         17.0,
         17.0,
         17.4,
         17.3,
         16.8,
         16.3,
         15.5,
         14.4,
         13.5,
         12.9,
         12.7,
         12.4,
         12.0,
         11.7,
         11.6,
         11.5,
         11.4,
         11.2,
         10.9,
         10.7,
         11.0,
         11.4,
         12.2,
         12.8,
         12.9,
         12.1,
         12.6,
         12.7,
         12.0,
         11.4,
         11.0,
         10.1,
         9.7,
         9.4,
         9.2,
         8.9,
         8.4,
         8.0,
         7.8,
         7.9,
         8.1,
         8.0,
         8.0,
         7.8,
         8.1,
         9.3,
         10.5,
         11.2,
         11.2,
         11.2,
         10.8,
         10.4,
         10.5,
         10.8,
         10.1,
         9.3,
         8.7,
         8.0,
         7.2,
         6.2,
         5.9,
         5.7,
         5.3,
         4.9,
         4.6,
         4.6,
         4.4,
         4.7,
         6.4,
         8.8,
         10.9,
         12.7,
         13.6,
         13.9,
         14.4,
         14.4,
         14.0,
         13.6,
         12.6,
         11.1,
         10.3,
         9.6,
         8.7,
         8.1,
         7.6,
         7.1,
         6.8,
         6.6,
         6.3,
         6.0,
         5.7,
         6.0,
         7.5,
         9.6,
         12.2,
         13.6,
         14.7,
         15.8,
         16.2,
         16.3,
         16.0,
         15.2,
         14.1,
         12.6,
         11.8,
         11.1,
         10.2,
         9.7,
         9.3,
         8.7,
         8.3,
         7.8,
         7.3,
         6.8,
         6.3,
         6.6,
         8.1,
         10.3,
         13.0,
         14.5,
         15.8,
         17.0,
         16.7,
         15.7,
         14.3,
         13.6,
         13.0,
         12.4,
         12.0,
         11.6,
         11.3,
         11.3,
         11.4,
         11.5,
         11.5,
         11.5,
         11.4,
         11.3,
         11.1,
         11.1,
         11.7,
         12.6,
         13.4,
         13.2,
         12.6,
         12.2,
         12.6,
         13.3,
         14.0,
         14.0,
         13.7,
         13.3,
         12.9,
         12.6,
         12.1,
         11.9,
         11.8
      ],
      "relativehumidity_2m":[
         88.0,
         90.0,
         90.0,
         90.0,
         93.0,
         95.0,
         93.0,
         84.0,
         74.0,
         67.0,
         53.0,
         45.0,
         47.0,
         47.0,
         44.0,
         47.0,
         47.0,
         52.0,
         58.0,
         65.0,
         68.0,
         74.0,
         73.0,
         75.0,
         76.0,
         76.0,
         75.0,
         76.0,
         78.0,
         81.0,
         85.0,
         85.0,
         83.0,
         77.0,
         75.0,
         70.0,
         77.0,
         74.0,
         75.0,
         74.0,
         78.0,
         77.0,
         81.0,
         87.0,
         86.0,
         83.0,
         89.0,
         93.0,
         94.0,
         93.0,
         94.0,
         94.0,
         94.0,
         92.0,
         89.0,
         85.0,
         77.0,
         69.0,
         63.0,
         64.0,
         63.0,
         69.0,
         73.0,
         73.0,
         69.0,
         74.0,
         78.0,
         80.0,
         83.0,
         87.0,
         92.0,
         92.0,
         93.0,
         94.0,
         94.0,
         94.0,
         94.0,
         93.0,
         92.0,
         84.0,
         76.0,
         69.0,
         61.0,
         53.0,
         52.0,
         50.0,
         51.0,
         54.0,
         55.0,
         59.0,
         68.0,
         73.0,
         78.0,
         83.0,
         85.0,
         87.0,
         88.0,
         89.0,
         90.0,
         90.0,
         91.0,
         91.0,
         89.0,
         83.0,
         74.0,
         63.0,
         57.0,
         53.0,
         48.0,
         46.0,
         44.0,
         45.0,
         49.0,
         55.0,
         62.0,
         65.0,
         68.0,
         71.0,
         73.0,
         74.0,
         76.0,
         78.0,
         79.0,
         81.0,
         83.0,
         84.0,
         83.0,
         77.0,
         69.0,
         59.0,
         55.0,
         53.0,
         51.0,
         52.0,
         57.0,
         64.0,
         69.0,
         74.0,
         80.0,
         83.0,
         86.0,
         88.0,
         88.0,
         88.0,
         87.0,
         87.0,
         86.0,
         86.0,
         86.0,
         87.0,
         86.0,
         82.0,
         77.0,
         73.0,
         77.0,
         83.0,
         90.0,
         89.0,
         87.0,
         83.0,
         82.0,
         82.0,
         82.0,
         81.0,
         80.0,
         80.0,
         80.0,
         81.0
      ],
      "windspeed_10m":[
         9.7,
         8.2,
         6.6,
         5.1,
         5.1,
         5.1,
         5.4,
         7.8,
         10.2,
         11.9,
         11.8,
         13.5,
         13.4,
         13.8,
         14.6,
         17.1,
         12.1,
         11.4,
         10.4,
         10.6,
         10.5,
         9.8,
         9.7,
         9.1,
         10.0,
         11.0,
         11.9,
         13.2,
         11.9,
         12.3,
         12.3,
         12.5,
         12.4,
         15.2,
         14.4,
         14.8,
         15.4,
         13.2,
         15.9,
         13.9,
         14.0,
         14.4,
         7.2,
         5.5,
         6.6,
         7.5,
         7.3,
         6.3,
         5.2,
         4.5,
         5.2,
         5.4,
         5.5,
         6.5,
         6.0,
         7.3,
         7.2,
         7.9,
         8.4,
         9.1,
         8.2,
         9.2,
         5.1,
         3.3,
         5.2,
         2.5,
         1.5,
         1.1,
         0.7,
         3.3,
         3.1,
         3.4,
         3.1,
         3.2,
         3.6,
         3.7,
         3.7,
         3.7,
         3.8,
         4.0,
         5.1,
         6.2,
         8.1,
         10.1,
         11.4,
         10.8,
         11.8,
         10.6,
         8.7,
         5.4,
         6.7,
         6.5,
         6.2,
         6.1,
         6.1,
         5.9,
         5.6,
         5.7,
         5.5,
         5.6,
         5.3,
         4.7,
         4.6,
         5.1,
         5.6,
         6.9,
         8.2,
         9.3,
         10.5,
         10.6,
         10.0,
         8.7,
         7.1,
         5.1,
         4.1,
         4.7,
         5.4,
         6.5,
         6.9,
         6.8,
         6.8,
         6.5,
         6.2,
         5.7,
         5.5,
         5.8,
         6.0,
         6.5,
         7.4,
         8.3,
         9.7,
         12.7,
         16.1,
         16.7,
         16.3,
         15.0,
         14.5,
         13.9,
         13.0,
         12.7,
         12.7,
         12.9,
         12.7,
         12.6,
         12.3,
         12.9,
         13.8,
         14.5,
         14.0,
         13.0,
         12.1,
         11.9,
         12.2,
         12.8,
         12.9,
         12.3,
         11.7,
         10.4,
         10.5,
         12.2,
         13.7,
         15.1,
         16.6,
         17.0,
         17.5,
         17.3,
         16.5,
         15.7
      ]
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I want to remove hourly parts as same as my question's want list.
Can you help me?

Comment: I THINk you do not need the hourly units also , you can use: response = requests.get('https://api.open-meteo.com/v1/forecast?latitude=52.52&longitude=13.41') without the ?hourly=