# requests.exceptions.JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 1 column 5 (char 4)

Tags: python, json, python-requests, insomnia

newb to python and requests here. I'm working with an API trying to get a JSON response but am only able to get the text version of it. My line of `resp_random_1_100_int.json()` returns the error:

`*** requests.exceptions.JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 1 column 4 (char 3) resp_random_1_100_int.json()`

but when I run my Insomnia(similar to Postman), I'm able to get a `JSON` response

here is my code:

```
resp_random_1_100_int = requests.get(
            f"http://numbersapi.com/random",
   params={
                "min": "0",
                "max": "100"
            }
        )

resp_random_1_100_int.json() # <-- gives error
```

Here is my response from insomnia:

```
{
    "text": "1 is the number of Gods in monotheism.",
    "number": 1,
    "found": true,
    "type": "trivia"
}
```

Here is what it looks like in insomnia:
[image]

Also, if I only `run resp_random_1_100_int.text`, the response comes back with a random fact and it works but I'm **not** able to access the other object attributes with `resp_random_1_100_int.number` or `resp_random_1_100_int.type`

i've tried setting the headers with `headers = {'Content-type': 'application/json'}` but still no luck

Any and all help/direction is appreciated.

Comment: This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6386366/10761353) has more on `<response_obj>.json()`. Alternatively, try seeing if running the content through `json.loads(<content>)` also throws an error.

Comment: Those two requests are not the same at all.  The one in the screenshot is `http://numbersapi.com/2`, but the python code is requesting `http://numbersapi.com/random?min=0&max=100`

Comment: @JohnGordon, you are right. that was my bad, I've updated the image.

Comment: Also, in the code, you assign `resp_random_1_100_int` as the response variable, but then you try to access `resp_random_year.json()`.  Those are two completely different variables.

Comment: @JohnGordon you are right. apparently, i've been at it for one too many hours. I've updated the question to correct the variable names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only difference from the following code and what you posted is that I specified the content type using the `headers` keyword argument:

```
import requests
resp_random_1_100_int = requests.get(
        f"http://numbersapi.com/random",
        headers={'Content-type': 'application/json'},
        params={"min": "0", "max": "100"})

 resp_random_1_100_int.json()
```

Returned:

```
{'text': '79 is the record for cumulative weeks at #1 on the Billboard charts, held by Elvis Presley.',
 'number': 79,
 'found': True,
 'type': 'trivia'}
```

Here are the versions of Python and Requests I used:

- Python 3.9.13
- Requests 2.28.1

Comment: Apparently, I didn't set everything correctly. I have no idea why yours worked and mine didn't when I tried setting the headers. thank you.